# Suppose that $x$ is a fixed nonnegative real number such that for all positive real numbers $\epsilon$, $0≤x≤\epsilon$. Show that $x=0$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $x$ is a fixed nonnegative real number such that for all positive real numbers $\epsilon$, $0≤x≤\epsilon$. Show that $x=0$.

Comment: Do you mean epsilon, as in $\epsilon$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the fact that for real $x,y$ with $x < y$ there is always a real $z$ with $x < z < y$.

Answer (score 1):

Another hint: Take a look at $\frac{x}{2}$. Now try a proof by contradiction.